# C# WPF auto button spacing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple StackPanel on a grid and I want buttons within that stack panel to take up all space available (space between them should be the same).
In case it's not clear, there's a pic:
[image]

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button MinWidth="115">OK</Button>
            <Button MinWidth="115">Cancel</Button>
            <Button MinWidth="115">Cancel</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

Is it possible or do I have to just enter margins manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `StackPanel` into a `Grid` instead (you'll need to refactor what you currently have slightly), and evenly space out all of the columns (using a width of `*`), and then set each button's alignment to left/center/right respectively, which will achieve the layout you're looking for.

Comment: Well actually this is inside the grid.. Do I really need another one?

Comment: Yes, why not? Nothing says you can't have a grid inside of a grid.

Comment: <Insert inception joke here> 
so it's normal to have all those column and grid definitions?

Comment: Yes, if that's what your application calls for. Don't get caught up in what the XAML looks like from afar (it's always going to look weird), and don't worry about putting controls inside of other controls. Often times I'll have 4 or 5 containers around a single object just to make it look/behave correctly.